# Переход с MYSQL на PDO, динамическое построение запросов

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Пошел 6-й месяц, как я учусь делать сайты. Сейчас делаю сайт для себя и решил переписать все 100+ страниц с MYSQL на PDO (только ради плейсхолдеров). Запросы типа `WHERE id=$var AND user=$var2` и т.д без проблем все переписал, но сейчас добрался до страниц, которые я писал на MYSQL и пользуясь легкостью вставки в запрос целых выражений в переменных исходящих из условных операторов, создал такой клубок, что мне кажется PDO с ним не разберется... Помогите советом! Как это все распутать и можно ли распутать...

**Запрос:**

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tovar ".$var1." vid='1' $var2 $var3 $var4 $var5 $var6 $var7 GROUP BY products_id ORDER BY $var8 $var9");
```

**Где:**

`$var1`  это

```
`IF что то 'JOIN table WHERE id = other_id AND значение IN('.$var из другого запроса .')' AND '$var2 из другого запроса = 'DISTINCT id''

else 
'WHERE' AND '$var4 из другого запроса = '*' AND $var3 из другого запроса = ''
```

И примерно такие же $var2, $var3, $var4, $var5, $var6, $var7, $var8, $var9,

Как думаете можно этот клубок распутать на PDO или проще повеситься?

---

Да я то могу в них разобраться, а вот PDO ругается. Разматывать надо конечно по одной ниточке. Вот к примеру как сделать это?

```
if ($_GET['up'] == 'one') $go_see = "AND see='1'" 

$count = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tovar WHERE vid='1' $go_see ''");

$count->execute([ ': go_see' => ??? ]);
```

Вариант просто вставить в запрос  `AND see=:плейсхолдер   где ': плейсхолдер ' => 1` и убрать таким образом переменную из запроса слишком очевиден и соответственно не подходит. Переменная $go_see может быть пустой или вместо AND иметь OR

И попутно еще вопрос. Будет ли безопасным такой вариант запроса?

```
$go_see= 'AND see=1';

$db->query("SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE vid='1' $go_see");
```

Везде пишут, что если в запросе есть переменная, то он уязвим! Это относится даже к тем переменным, которые назначаются внутри скрипта без использования внешних данных?

Comment: Ничего страшного в переменных нет, страшны данные в запросе, особенно данные, которые пришли извне.

Comment: `переписать все 100+ страниц` - а зачем держать запросы и соединения на каждой странице?

Comment: Соединение конечно в одном месте, но запросы ВСЕ разные и шаблон к ним не применить. Не потому, что так мне захотелось, а потому, что каждая страница выполняет свою роль и контактирует с базой исходя из своих задачь. Там где задачи одинаковые, там и запрос один конечно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По хорошему, Вам нужно внедрить какой-никакой SqlBuilder.

Можно, конечно, строить запросы вручную:

```
$where = [];
$params = [];

$where[] = 'vid = ?';
$params[] = '1';

if ($_GET['up'] == 'one') {
  $where[] = 'see = ?';
  $params[] = 1;
}
if (!empty($_GET['ids'])) {
  $values = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', $_GET['ids']);
  if (!empty($values)) {
    $in = str_repeat('?,', count($values)-1).'?';
    $where[] = "id in ($in)"; // Только плейсхолдеры попадают в запрос
    $params = array_merge($params, $values);
  }
}

$where = $where ? 'WHERE ' . implode(' AND ', $where) : '';
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tovar $where";
// SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tovar WHERE vid = ? AND see = ? AND id IN (?,?,?)

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Константы или значения из белого списка совершенно необязательно отделять от запроса, тем не менее - это хорошая привычка.

Comment: vp_arth  Спасибо за развернутый ответ. Ваш код я буду разбирать, что бы понять что там к чему, но хочу сейчас подвести итог: 1) Я правильно понимаю, что в плейсхолдеры PDO нельзя вставить что то, что не является данными? тоесть :name => "Ivan" это пройдет, а :name => "AND name='Ivan'" не пройдет? И без "надстроек" и "бубнов" сделать динамический-защищенный запрос не реально?  2)  Переменная $var=$_GET["id"] ОПАСНАЯ,  а  переменная $var=69  БЕЗОПАСНАЯ и ее можно вставлять в запрос?

Comment: Всё верно, если бы логику можно было передавать среди данных - смысл плейсхолдеров был бы утерян - инъекции вернулись бы в новом качестве.

Comment: vp_arth Подскажите плз еще немного. Собственно вопрос: Этот код ниже можно назвать безопасным? $name = $_GET['name'] $go_sort = 'AND user=:name'; $count = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE vid=1 $go_sort"); $count->execute([':name' => $name]); Можно ли быть уверенным, что так SQL инъекция не пройдет?

Answer (score 0):

Переписывать запросы однозначно. Вы же сами в них не можете разобраться. Если есть проблемы с переписыванием - задавайте вопросы и приводите конкретные примеры

Comment: @АндрейСергеев, комментарии в основном не предназначены для кода. Предполагается, что важную дополнительную информацию Вы добавите в текст вопроса.